# Aws S3 Error During Multitransfer

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using uploadDirectory method of s3 client to upload the directory from local to S3 server . Code i have written to do the same is as follows :

try{

```
            $this->s3Client->uploadDirectory($directoryLocalPath, $bucket, $keyPrefix, array(
                'params'      => array('ACL' => 'public-read'),
                'concurrency' => 20,
                'debug'       => true
            ));
            }
            catch(Exception $exce)
            {
                    echo $exce->getMessage();
            }
```

It starts uploading the directory but after uploading some files it throws an exception as follows :

Errors during multi transfer
(Guzzle\Http\Exception\RequestException) phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Message/Request.php line 569

```
Error completing request

#0 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Message/Request.php(378): Guzzle\Http\Message\Request->processResponse(Array)
#1 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Message/EntityEnclosingRequest.php(49): Guzzle\Http\Message\Request->setState('complete', Array)
#2 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(290): Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest->setState('complete', Array)
#3 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(248): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->processResponse(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlHandle), Array)
#4 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(231): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->processMessages()
#5 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(215): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->executeHandles()
#6 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(109): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->perform()
#7 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMultiProxy.php(94): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->send()
#8 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Client.php(386): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMultiProxy->send()
#9 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Client.php(279): Guzzle\Http\Client->sendMultiple(Array)
#10 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php(284): Guzzle\Http\Client->send(Array)
#11 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Service/Client.php(233): Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient->send(Array)
#12 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Service/Client.php(140): Guzzle\Service\Client->executeMultiple(Array)
#13 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Aws/S3/Sync/AbstractSync.php(118): Guzzle\Service\Client->execute(Array)
#14 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Aws/S3/Sync/AbstractSync.php(107): Aws\S3\Sync\AbstractSync->transferCommands(Array)
#15 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Aws/S3/Sync/AbstractSync.php(64): Aws\S3\Sync\AbstractSync->transferFiles(Array)
#16 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php(572): Aws\S3\Sync\AbstractSync->transfer()
#17 ./awsAdmin.class.php(91): Aws\S3\S3Client->uploadDirectory('/var/www/cloudi...', '99acres', 'aman/', Array)
#18 ./CloudOrigImages.class.php(98): awsAdmin->uploadDirectory('/var/www/cloudi...', '99acres', 'aman/')
#19 ./Cron_onetime_daily_deletion.php(22): cloudOrigImages->syncingOnS3()
#20 {main}
```

(Guzzle\Http\Exception\RequestException) phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Message/Request.php line 569

```
Error completing request

#0 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Message/Request.php(378): Guzzle\Http\Message\Request->processResponse(Array)
#1 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Message/EntityEnclosingRequest.php(49): Guzzle\Http\Message\Request->setState('complete', Array)
#2 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(290): Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest->setState('complete', Array)
#3 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(248): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->processResponse(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlHandle), Array)
#4 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(231): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->processMessages()
#5 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(215): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->executeHandles()
#6 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(109): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->perform()
#7 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMultiProxy.php(94): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->send()
#8 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Client.php(386): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMultiProxy->send()
#9 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Client.php(279): Guzzle\Http\Client->sendMultiple(Array)
#10 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php(284): Guzzle\Http\Client->send(Array)
#11 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Service/Client.php(233): Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient->send(Array)
#12 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Guzzle/Service/Client.php(140): Guzzle\Service\Client->executeMultiple(Array)
#13 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Aws/S3/Sync/AbstractSync.php(118): Guzzle\Service\Client->execute(Array)
#14 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Aws/S3/Sync/AbstractSync.php(107): Aws\S3\Sync\AbstractSync->transferCommands(Array)
#15 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Aws/S3/Sync/AbstractSync.php(64): Aws\S3\Sync\AbstractSync->transferFiles(Array)
#16 phar:///usr/local/php-5.4.19/lib/php/AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar/Aws/S3/S3Client.php(572): Aws\S3\Sync\AbstractSync->transfer()
#17 ./awsAdmin.class.php(91): Aws\S3\S3Client->uploadDirectory('/var/www/cloudi...', '99acres', 'aman/', Array)
#18 ./CloudOrigImages.class.php(98): awsAdmin->uploadDirectory('/var/www/cloudi...', '99acres', 'aman/')
#19 ./Cron_onetime_daily_deletion.php(22): cloudOrigImages->syncingOnS3()
#20 {main}
```

Any Help would be thankful !!